# Efficient method to detect large probability shifts in HMM model output

Tags: r, optimization, hidden-markov-model, change-point

I am using an HMM model, the specifics of which I cannot disclose. However, my objective is to detect significant transitions in the model's output probability distribution. This probability corresponds to the likelihood of observing a 1 or a 0 at each index value. In an ideal scenario, we would only observe probabilities of either 0 or 1. The diagram below illustrates the model's output distribution for some generated data. Green dots represent some priors, while the black dots denote values interpolated linearly due to missing data.

My aim is to find a computational approach to pinpoint the indices where the model is most likely to transition from state 0 to state 1 or vice versa.

Considering that linear interpolation doesn't contribute new information to this task, I thought to use the values from the prior distribution (green dots) as potential candidates for identifying the index values at the transition points. My plan was to calculate the standard deviation of a specific window around each candidate to select the most likely transition points. Unfortunately, I have not been successful in finding a solution that is applicable to a range of potential model distributions. I am thus seeking a universal solution to this challenge.

All suggestions are welcome, though I would particularly appreciate a solution that incorporates an existing R routine.

**EDIT I** : It seems like that I want some kind of changepoint test statistic for my data. Since the distribution follows a uniform distribution it seems that a CUSUM test should be useful. Packages like `cpt` or `ncpc` can be used for this. I tried those already but only with decent success. Any helpful recommendations for specific parameters or things I should be aware of are highly recommended!

[image]

Comment: Is it a 1st order (or generally, stationary) HMM? If so, the probability of transitioning is only a function of a short local context, and it’ll be the same anywhere in the sequence that contains those same values.

Comment: The models output at time n only depends on n-1 for the forward and only on n+1 on the backward algorithm. Does this classify the model as 1st order? Given that I can easily obtain the values from the transition probability function how do I evaluate what is the most likely index for a jump? I search for some kind of selection algorithm.

Comment: I just checked that. The transition probability is indeed everywhere the same in the sequence.